# Collecting Gmail multiple inbox data with same subject

Tags: python, gmail

I wanted to collect Gmail inbox emails which have the same subject into a notepad or something using Python. Gmail provides an option to filter emails with same subject but my requirement is I have thousand of emails with that subject, I want to collect the body of those all emails into a notepad using Python. I know its not impossible.Please help me guys.

Comment: You can start by reading this tutorial to get familiar with using python with emails since you have posted any issues with code sounds you like you haven't tried anything yet. I hope this gives you a good idea on where to start.
[https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter16/](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter16/)

Comment: Thanks. Can u please tell me how to prevent my python file from editing by malicious users.I want some security that no one could edit my python file.

Comment: I don't understand, how would malicious have access to your file? I would recommend to just keep any sensitive information out of your python file like passwords and tokens so you won't have to worry about anyone accessing the file.

Comment: but man the file would be on public server.i dont want anyone to edit my file and play with it.i hope u r getting my point.Is there any way i can lock the file from editing only.Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should google this I can't think of a solution. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

1. enable IMAP for gmail (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=de)
2. Use imaplib to fetch all emails (https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html)
3. parse emails

You might even be able to fetch emails by filter but that is for you to find out.